# RxJs forkjoin deprecated

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

I have checked my project that forkjoin is being deprecated, since `forkjoin` is deprecated from angular what is the best option to use instead?

Comment: Method signature changed, it now accepts an array of Observables. See https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: @AldinBradaric you can put that as answer. People will not notice that from comments as easily.

Comment: Think there should be a deprecation notice next to the warning/error on what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method signature changed, it now accepts an array of `ObservableInput` or a dictionary `Object` of `ObservableInput`.

*`ObservableInput` - Valid types that can be converted to observables.*

See [rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin)

> Accepts an Array of `ObservableInput` or a dictionary `Object` of
> `ObservableInput` and returns an `Observable` that emits either an
> array of values in the exact same order as the passed array, or a
> dictionary of values in the same shape as the passed dictionary.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The sighted documentation also states that it accepts a dictionary. Apart from that using a dictionary presently gives a deprecation warning, which I think is an error

Comment: Edited the answer for better clarity